# Overflow when trying to load range into a variant array

Tags: excel, vba

Just got this error, which is really weird. The code worked fine before, now it doesn't. I tried to restart Excel but got the same error. This is the part of the code that produces the error:

```
Dim EmpRes as Worksheet
Set EmpRes = Worksheets("EmpRes")

Dim ER() As Variant
ER = EmpRes.Range("Q1").CurrentRegion  ' <- This line is the cause of the Overflow error
```

The sheet EmpRes is empty when you run the code. Data in another sheet is then autofiltered and copied into it. In total there's 518 rows and 36 columns in the sheet when the error occurs.

If I change it to:

```
ER = EmpRes.Range("A1:C5")
```

it works. But

```
ER = EmpRes.Range("A1:C100")
```

doesn't.

Anyone knows why this might be?
/Jens

Comment: Maybe use `Debug.Print EmpRes.Range("Q1").CurrentRegion.Address` before the problem line to see what the current region is. Also, to load things into an array, you could just declare `ER` as a simple `Variant` (so just use `Dim ER As Variant` rather than `ER()`) and then just use `ER = EmpRes.Range("Q1").CurrentRegion.Value` (once you make sure that this range is what you think it is).

Comment: ````Debug.Print EmpRes.Range("Q1").CurrentRegion.Address```` printed ````$A$1:$AJ$518```` So no error there. It's around 18000 cells, is that a lot? Some rows contain strings, two contain dates, some contain integers and some are empty.

Comment: Changing from ````ER()```` to ````ER```` didn't help. Tried with and without ````.value````

Comment: I'm using Excel 365 64bit/win10_64bit and couldn't replicate your problem. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the same version. The thing is, this code worked before. I changed some stuff today elsewhere in the code today and the error came. But what I changed had nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: I would look at whether any merged cells or any hidden rows/columns are causing issues.

Comment: No merged cells or hidden rows in this sheet.

Comment: I tried to delete row after row and even when there was just 2 rows left I got the error. When I deleted the second row, leaving only the header, the code worked.

Comment: Adding ````EmpRes.Range("A20:AX600").Clear```` before the code doesn't help either.

Comment: Changing all cells to the word "Status" worked. Not sure what that implies though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it. I have no clue why the problem emerged in the first place though.

Somehow the cells in the column AB, which contains 8 digit numbers, were formatted as dates. The data in those cells showed up as `#################`

Even if I changed them into integers they would change back when I ran the code again.

By adding the line
`EmpRes.Range("AB2:AB" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "0"`
before the code the problem was solved. Then the cells showed the 8 digit numbers again. And I was able to load the range into the array!